# How to change text animation using setInterval and styling by CSS?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm making a portfolio website. I want the background to be text automatically changing like 'HTML' to 'CSS' to 'JavaScript'. However, I also want them to change, not plainly, but in animation like zoomIn and zoomOut in animation.css. In other words, when the text 'HTML' disappear before changing to CSS, it gets smalller until you can't see and appear again bigger and bigger to 'CSS'. Sorry for the complication.

Currently, I have text changing overtime by implementing setInterval over array of words.

index.html

```
<h1 id="change"></h1>
```

main.js

```
const symbols = ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript']
count = 0
let inthandle = setInterval(() => {
  document.getElementById("change").innerHTML = symbols[count];
  count = (count + 1) % symbols.length
}, 2000)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this zoom out transition by changing twice the [`scale` `transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/transform) for each element in symbols.

Note that the transition time must be half the setInterval period.

`count` needs to be inscremented by 2 to change the text, but the `.out` class id added then removed in alternance for each step.

The time interval has been divided by two to keep the same rate as before.

The `h1` element also have to keep fixed size and text centered to give the illusion that it is the same text changing.

Finally the iteration callback is forced called once to immediately start the animation.

```js
const symbols = ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript'];
let count = 0;
const element = document.getElementById("change");
const iteration = () => {
  element.innerHTML = symbols[parseInt(count / 2, 10) % symbols.length];
  if (count % 2 !== 0) {
    element.classList.add("out");
  } else {
    element.classList.remove("out");
  }
  count++;
  // if you're affraid the code could run for so long that it could fail,
  // 6 is enough (number of elems * 2)
  if (count === symbols.length * 2) {
      count = 0;
  }
};
let inthandle = setInterval(iteration, 1000);
iteration();
```

```css
#change {
transition: transform 0.5s;
display: inline-block;
width: 200px;
text-align: center;
}


.out {
  transform: scale(0);
}
```

```html
<h1 id="change">HTML</h1>
```

Comment: Perhaps the count should’t increment without limitation.

Comment: Maybe but why? In javascript the maximum integral number is 2^53-1. If count is incremented by 1 each second, then the number will reach javascript's limit in 285 427 017 years. Not worth reseting it for me...

Comment: Added a limitation on count as suggested by @Ucho

Comment: The  2^53-1 is really big number.

Comment: Yes but it's still a float 64 (as all javascript numbers) and occupies the same amount of memory as 1. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER and http://2ality.com/2012/04/number-encoding.html

Comment: Yes, yes. You’re right. It was just tough not actual expostulation.

Answer (score 1):

You could also add an a CSS animation 3 times longer than your interval.

```js
const symbols = ['HTML', 'CSS', 'JavaScript']
count = 0
let inthandle = setInterval(() => {
  document.getElementById("change").innerHTML = symbols[count];
  count = (count + 1) % symbols.length
}, 2000)
```

```css
#change {
  text-align: center;
  animation: 6s colors infinite;
}

@keyframes colors {
  16.66%,
  50%,
  56%,
  83.31% {
    color: tomato;
    font-size: 3rem;
  }
  0%,
  33.33%,
  66.65%,
  100% {
    color: lightblue;
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 id="change"></h1>
```

Inside animation, you can use `transform` to avoid content jumping